# CSV file not properly filled up with details

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

```
import csv
TextFileContent = open('tickets.txt')
with open('example4.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Author', 'ticket number', 'Revision']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for TextLine in TextFileContent:
        if 'Revision:' in TextLine:
            tmp=TextLine.replace('Revision:', "")
            print(tmp)
            writer.writerow({'Revision': tmp})
        elif 'Author:' in TextLine:
            tmp=TextLine.replace("Author:", "")
            print(tmp)
            writer.writerow({'Author': tmp})
        elif 'Contributes to:' in TextLine:
            tmp=TextLine.replace("Contributes to:", "")
            print(tmp)
            writer.writerow({'ticket number': tmp})
```

Hi all i have developed above python script to extract "Author", "Ticket" and "revision" details from text file and then filled up that infomation to CSV file.

Now i am able to extract all information but the data not correctly filled up in CSV file.

the text file content is like below

```
Revision: 22904
Author: Userx
Contributes to: CF-1159


Revision: 22887
Author: Usery
Contributes to: CF-955


Revision: 22884
Author: UserZ
Contributes to: CPL-7768
```

And i want result in CSV file like below

```
Author  ticket number   Revision
Userx    CF-1159        22904
Usery    CF-955         22887
UserZ    CPL-7768       22884
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code writes a row as soon as it finds *any* field instead of waiting until it has read a full set of fields. The following edit waits for a full set and then writes the row.

```
with open('/tmp/out.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Author', 'ticket number', 'Revision']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    row = {}
    for TextLine in TextFileContent:
        if 'Revision:' in TextLine:
            row['Revision'] = TextLine.replace('Revision: ', "")
        elif 'Author:' in TextLine:
            row['Author'] = TextLine.replace("Author: ", "")
        elif 'Contributes to:' in TextLine:
            row['ticket number'] = TextLine.replace("Contributes to: ", "")
        if len(row) == len(fieldnames):
            writer.writerow(row)
            row = {}
```

Note that this will not function correctly unless all records contain all fields.